# Barristers bookcase needs love

Tags: repair, wooden-furniture

I am looking for some direction about some love I can give to a barrister bookcase I found for dirt cheap.

It has some loss at a corner and bottom and I'm thinking it may be best to buy new ( *real* ) wood sides and use a router to make the shelves and door hardware line up to new sides. It has real wood on top, shelves and doors but the sides are found to be a composite when you peel back the edge piece. ( *See photos* ).

The finish and most everything else about it is fine ( *it needs to be cleaned* ) so I'd like to keep it as close to original as possible. I don't think it's an antique considering the composite sides and plastic hardware on the doors but still don't want it to die if I can fix it up.

Any advice or help is appreciated!!

Pics were too large to upload so here is a link:

https://photos.app.goo.gl/U2AMhQuKbLn6j22h6

Comment: I was going to add the photos but When i click on the link i do not see any photos. May be better suited for the Woodworkers stack. https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/

Comment: No photo at link.  But I want to see the adopted bookcase!

Comment: Apologies, hopefully you can see them now